# Using get_field with specific postID returns empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use get_field in a loop to retrieve some custom field values but
when using get_field('container', post_id) the value is always empty.

I tried to even use it inside the block file and the same happens.

```
  $container = get_field('container'); // this works
  $test_container = get_field('container', 144); //this returns empty,  post id === 144
```

Comment: use `get_post(144)` to test if it can retrieve post data for you

Comment: ```get_post(144)``` returns the post data

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the_field() function.

In ACF the_field() function is used to display the value of a specific field. it is same as get_field().
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

```
<?php if( get_field('container') ): ?>
   <p><?php the_field('container', 144); ?> </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you using should work but if it's not working for any reason. You can also use

```
get_post_meta(); //to retrieve the value.
```

Comment: the only thing that returns from this is 
```[_edit_lock] => Array 
(
  [0] => 1560233544:1
) ```